# How to apply UItableView with Custom ScrollView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uiscrollview, xcode4.6, tpkeyboardavoiding

I have a UITableview subclass.

I need to use custom scrollview ie, 'TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView' it is used for text fields up when edit the textField.

How can I apply custom scrollView to tableView programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make your table view a subclass of `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` instead of `UITableView`?